# NSPredicate Out of Order / Extra Information

Tags: ios, swift, nspredicate

Lets say I have two objects:

- Big Bike (size=Big, type=Bike)
- Small Bike (size=Small, type=Bike)

If I make the following query: "Big Blue Bike," I should receive back the object Big Bike.

I am trying to figure out how to implement this from the `NSPredicate` function.

Currently, I am using something along the lines of the following:

```
let typePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "type CONTAINS[c] %@", text);
```

However, as "Blue" is not in the object, the predicate will eliminate all objects from the filtered array.

Is there a `NSPredicate` format which will allow me to take into account these extraneous statements and still return Big Bike from "Big Blue Bike"?

Comment: How about using the `init(block:)` initializer of `NSPredicate`? There you don’t have to remember the format syntax and you can just write Swift code.

Answer (score 0):

i just give one simple example how you can achieve this, this is just an example just to give some idea so that you can proceed further, let say we will create a class named `Vehicle` later we will create 2 other classes as just you mentioned, `BigBike` and `SmallBike` and after that will see how to parse this by using your query string

let's create a class called `Vehicle`  this class holds all the info, this will be useful if you have single type objects in array.

```
 import Foundation

 enum Size {
   case big
   case small
 }

 enum Type {
   case Bike
   case Car
 }

 class Vehicle:NSObject {
    let size:Size
    let type:Type

    init(with vehicleType:Type, andSize vehicleSize:Size) {
      self.size = vehicleSize
      self.type = vehicleType
    }

    override func value(forKey key: String) -> Any? {
      if key == "size" {
           if self.size == .big {
               return "big"
           } else if self.size == .small {
               return "small"
           }
     } else if key == "type" {
           if self.type == .Bike {
              return "bike"
           } else if self.type == .Car {
              return "car"
          }
     }
     return nil
  }

  func vehicleDescription() {
      let aType = (type == .Bike) ? "Bike" : "Car"
      let aSize = (size == .big) ? "Big" : "Small"
      print("this vehicle is \(aType) of size \(aSize)")
  }
}
```

now we will create two objects that you mentioned in the question `BigBike` and `SmallBike` like below, simply subclass of `Vehicle` class

```
import Foundation
class BigBike:Vehicle {

}
```

and one more `SmallBike`

```
import Foundation
class SmallBike:Vehicle {

}
```

Now you have 2 classes `BigBike` and `SmallBike` now lets filter these objects created from these 2 classes,
you have the array contains object of these 2 classes, for example lets take an array and append object of `BigBike` and `SmallBike` like below,

```
var vehicles:NSMutableArray =  NSMutableArray()
//add some objects for above array like below for testing:
func setupVehicleArray() {
    for i in 0..<15 {
        if i < 5 {
            let vehicle = BigBike(with: .Bike, andSize: .big)
            vehicles.add(vehicle)//append(vehicle)
        }
        if i > 5 && i < 10 {
            let vehicle = BigBike(with: .Bike, andSize: .small)
            vehicles.add(vehicle)
        }
        if i > 11 && i < 15 {
            let vehicle = BigBike(with: .Bike, andSize: .big)
            vehicles.add(vehicle)
        }
    }
}
```

now `vehicles` contains objects of `BigBike` and `SmallBike`, now let make query and filter these objects using predicate

```
 func makeQuery() {
    let query = "big blue bike"
    let aPredicate = NSPredicate { (obj:Any?, test:[String : Any]?) -> Bool in
        var checkFurther = false
        if let aObj = obj as? Vehicle {
            if let size = aObj.value(forKey: "size") as? String {
                if query.contains(size) {
                    checkFurther = true
                }
            }
            if let type = aObj.value(forKey: "type") as? String {
                if query.contains(type) {
                    if checkFurther {
                        return true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false
        }

    let filteredArray = vehicles.filtered(using: aPredicate)
    for aVehicle:Vehicle in filteredArray as! [Vehicle] {
        aVehicle.vehicleDescription()
    }
}
```

This is just the sample example that you can try, gives values for other queries also and you can modify predicate according to your requirements.

above gives the result like below:

`this vehicle is Bike of size Big
this vehicle is Bike of size Big
this vehicle is Bike of size Big
this vehicle is Bike of size Big
this vehicle is Bike of size Big
this vehicle is Bike of size Big
this vehicle is Bike of size Big
this vehicle is Bike of size Big`

if you change the query string to `small green bike` you will get the result like 
`this vehicle is Bike of size Small
this vehicle is Bike of size Small
this vehicle is Bike of size Small
this vehicle is Bike of size Small`

Hope this helps..  :)